# Error after adding string resources to Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm getting following error after I added string resources to my compose multiplatform project:

```
Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Node.getNodeValue()" because the return value of "org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap.getNamedItem(String)" is null
at org.jetbrains.compose.resources.GenerateResClassTask.getStringIds(GenerateResClassTask.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.compose.resources.GenerateResClassTask.fileToResourceItems
```

I'm trying to build web target. The gradle build fails with above error.

This is my `strings.xml` file

```xml
<resources>
    <string>Hello World</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't giving name to the string entries :P. This compiled successfully

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World</string>
</resources>
```